# API view returning { "detail": "Not found." },

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```py
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_image = models.URLField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('uploads.Posts', related_name='post_user')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Posts(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

These are my models, I have created a serializer for Posts and nested it under a UserPostSerializer.

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        exclude = ('id', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'is_deleted')


class UserPostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id', 'posts',)
```

However, when I create a view like this:

```py
class UserPostsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserPostsSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        response = Response(serializer.data)
        return response
```

my API returns `{ "detail": "Not found." }`

Ideally, the view should list all the users along with their posts.
Something like:

```
{
   "user_id": "abcd",
   "posts": {  
       "url": "http:....com",
       "description": "Lorem ipsum"
       }  
}
```

Comment: what is your request look like ? and what was set up for the url path in the project for that view?

Comment: @lostbard path('', include('users.urls')) in the main urls and
path('user/posts', UserPostsView.as_view(), name='user posts') within the app that contains the view.

Comment: and if using a browser or wget ot postman what method and full url is being used when it returns not found ?

Comment: postman and yes, full url is being used

Comment: using the GET method?

Comment: yeah, ofcourse.

Comment: If you want to create and display the nested values there is nothing to do with the list method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the ordering of the URLs, I had called it this way:

```
    urlpatterns = [
                   path('list', UserListView.as_view(), name='user list'),
                   path('<str:id>', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user detail'),
                   path('posts', UserPostsView.as_view(), name='user posts')]
```

this way it was mapping my request to UserDetailView, since < str:id > is a catch-all and was called before 'posts', Django was trying to find an user with an user_id 'posts'.
The URL for my UserPostsView should have preceded the URL for my UserDetailView, like:

```
   urlpatterns = [
                  path('list', UserListView.as_view(), name='user list'),
                  path('posts', UserPostsView.as_view(), name='user posts'),
                  path('<str:id>', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user detail')]
```

This fixes the error and I am able to see the data in the required format.